# Why is my "defined name" (range) value not being set with this Spreadsheet Light code?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, xlsx, named-ranges, spreadsheetlight

I've got this code to apply a "header" (big, top-of-the-sheet "title") to a sheet:

```
// Initialize
private static SLDocument sl;
. . .
sl = new SLDocument();

// Create a Style
SLStyle styleHeading = sl.CreateStyle();
styleHeading.SetFont(FontSchemeValues.Major, 36);
styleHeading.Font.Italic = true;
styleHeading.Font.FontName = "Candara";

// Create a Defined Name (Range) and give it a value and style
sl.SetDefinedName("UnitName", "Sheet1!$A$1:$A$13"); 
sl.SetCellValue("UnitName", "Pennsylvania Platypi Presumptuously Parasailing");
sl.SetCellStyle("UnitName", styleHeading);

// Save the sheet
string appDataFolder = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/");
string spreadsheetLightFilename = "PlatypiTest.xlsx";
string fullspreadsheetLightPath = Path.Combine(appDataFolder, spreadsheetLightFilename);
sl.SaveAs(fullspreadsheetLightPath);
```

Note: I verified that "Sheet1" was right with this code:

```
var nameList = sl.GetSheetNames();
string s = nameList[0]; // "s" is "Sheet1"
```

The file *is* created and saved, but it is devoid of content; when I open it, cell A1 is highlighted, but is content-free.

Am I missing a vital step, or going about this completely wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you doing is logically fine.

This line

```
sl.SetDefinedName("UnitName", "Sheet1!$A$1:$A$13");
```

indeed creates a named range. You can see it if you open the resulting file in Excel and look at the cell selector:

[image]

or the Name Manager:

[image]

The problem is though that Spreadsheet Light has a very basic support for Defined names - basically all you can do is to create a name and use it inside the formulas. All methods that manipulate content expect single cell reference. Btw, all these methods do not throw exception if you don't pass a valid cell reference, but return `bool` indicating success/failure.

For instance, if you change your code to

```
bool success1 = sl.SetCellValue("UnitName", "Pennsylvania Platypi Presumptuously Parasailing");
bool success2 = sl.SetCellStyle("UnitName", styleHeading);
```

you will see that both `success` variables are `false`.

Shortly, if you want to bring some content to the Excel file, you should do it cell by cell. It even does not support regular (unnamed) ranges.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, at least, you could do it this way:

```
// from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36481802/what-is-the-analogue-to-excel-interops-worksheet-usedrange-rows-in-spreadsheet
var stats = sl.GetWorksheetStatistics();
var rowcount = stats.NumberOfRows;

SLStyle entireSheetRangeStyle = sl.CreateStyle();
entireSheetRangeStyle.// (set style vals)
. . .
sl.SetRowStyle(1, rowcount, entireSheetRangeStyle);
```