# What is the analogue to Excel Interop's Worksheet.UsedRange.Rows in Spreadsheet Light?

Tags: c#, worksheet, rowcount, spreadsheetlight

Using Excel Interop, you can get the count of rows in use by a sheet like so:

```
_xlSheet.UsedRange.Rows
```

(where "_xlSheet" is an Excel.Worksheet).

What is the equivalent in Spreadsheet Light?

You can add a worksheet like so:

```
var sl = new SLDocument();
. . .
sl.AddWorksheet("SheetsToTheWind");
```

...but how can you then access that worksheet to interrogate it for its used row count?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After adding the worksheet it is active as well. That means that you can get the `WorksheetStatistics` from the method `GetWorksheetStatistics`. That statistics instance has a `NumberOfRows` property:

```
// NOTE: The information is only current at point of retrieval. 
var stats = sl.GetWorksheetStatistics();
var rowcount = stats.NumberOfRows;
```

If you want to to know the rowcount of all sheets you can do:

```
foreach(var name in sl.GetSheetNames())
{
    sl.SelectWorksheet(name);
    var stats = sl.GetWorksheetStatistics();
    var rowcount = stats.NumberOfRows;    
    Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("sheet '{0}' has {1} rows", name, rowcount));
}
```

Comment: If I want to access NumberOfRows at various places/points, will I need to call GetWorksheetStatistics() first each time, or does accessing NumberOfRows make sure that the count is current?

Comment: The docs for GetWorksheetStatistics says: *NOTE: The information is only current at point of retrieval.* @B.ClayShannon

Answer (score 0):

Adding to rene's answer:

Since accessing the Statistics' NumberOfRows property does not automagically update (you must call GetWorksheetStatistics() each time to get the up-to-date stats), I found it handy to write this helper method:

```
private int GetCurrentNumberOfRows()
{
    // This reference to "sl" assumes that you have declared "SLDocument sl;" and
    // instantiated it ("sl = new SLDocument();"), perhaps in your class' constructor
    var stats = sl.GetWorksheetStatistics();
    return stats.NumberOfRows;
}
```

..and then call it as needed:

```
int lastRow = GetCurrentNumberOfRows();
```